# How to extend spring by configuring spring xml

Tags: java, xml, spring

In a Spring 4 application, we are extending **`PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`** to do some custom task during resolving properties.

To register our new class (`MyPropertyConfigurer`) o Spring we use the following class:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
  @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new MyPropertyConfigurer();
    }

}
```

As a matter of curiosity, can I add my new bean to Spring with `spring.xml` instead of using the `@Configuration` annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, my problem was fixed simply with placing the bean of my class in my `Springbeans.xml` file like below:

```
<beans:bean class="MyPropertyConfigurer"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can very well use a combination of both Spring based xml and java based config in your spring application.

You have to use

```
@ImportResource({"classpath:sampleapp.xml"})
```

along with

```
@Configuration
```

Look at the sample post below which explains it:

[Mixing xml and java config with spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365366/mixing-xml-and-java-config-with-spring)

Comment: Yes, But how can I define `MyPropertyConfigurer` in `xml` and use it as `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502383/spring-loading-propertysourcesplaceholderconfigurer-from-jboss-context