# Override Spring 4 classes

Tags: java, xml, spring, extend

To override an spring class (for example `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`) in spring we use below config in spring xml:

```
<beans:bean class="MyPropertyConfigurer"/>
```

And

```
public class MyPropertyConfigurerextends extends PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer {

 @Override
protected void doProcessProperties {
   //....
}
```

Please see [How to extend spring by configuring spring xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37252864/how-to-extend-spring-by-configuring-spring-xml/37299469#37299469)

It works fine, but my question is:

1. How does spring find and replace this bean with its internal bean?!
2. Is this a recommended way or we should do it in other ways?
3. Is `beans:bean` in xml, same as using a `@Configuration` bean?

Comment: 1/ what do you mean, 2/ why not? 3/ if you mean `@Bean` in a `@Configuration` class, then yes

Comment: Dear @RC thanks. about first question... Let me ask this way...  Please  correct me! ... In my example here is what happens, spring come to line `<beans:bean class="MyPropertyConfigurer"/>` It finds that the `MyPropertyConfigurer` is type of `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`, now it searches all its internal classes (which are around 800 beans, if we use other spring projects it will be even more) It finds that there is a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean, so it replace it with its own.  If we spring find another `beans:bean` it will repeat above....

Comment: Euh I think you should read on inheritance, "A extends B" when A is a spring managed bean does **not** mean that spring will look for some "B" managed bean